# Excluir SharedPreferences criadas dinamicamentes

Tags: java, android

Para não precisar ficar refazendo requisições que já foram trazidas do servidor eu persisto elas usando SharedPreferences... Só que elas são criadas dinamicamente no meu app. exemplo:

```
// essa key é unica para cada post
// ex: MINHA_KEI_1, depois MINHA_KEI_2, e assim por diante...

SharedPreferences  save = contexto.getSharedPreferences(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor saveEdit = save.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();

String jsonPost = gson.toJson(posts);
saveEdit.putString("POST", jsonPost);

saveEdit.commit();
```

Só que depois de um tempo, eu quero excluir todas elas para o app mão ficar muito grande.

Como fazer as exclusão de todas elas de uma vez, mesmo sem eu saber a KEY?

Pensei em criar uma sharedPreferences com as keys geradas, e então percorrer cada uma e excluir... não sei se ha outra maneira.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, para excluir o shared preferences basta utilizar o seguinte trecho de código :

```
SharedPreferences save = contexto.getSharedPreferences(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor saveEdit = save.edit();
saveEdit.clear(); 
saveEdit.commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá, a documentação oficial do método não cita nenhum método para remover todas as sharedPrefferences do teu app via código sem citar a chave da shared.

O único momento que ela limpa completamente (e sem necessidade da chave) é quando o app é removido - mas programaticamente, não acredito que haja uma maneira de limpar conforme é feito na desinstalação do app.